# Php sessions weird behavior

Tags: php, session

My tmp directory is not accessible by php.Hence, sessions can't really work(And they don't)
but in this case, they do for some unknown reason.

Here's the scenario,

I have a page index.php which verifies a users credentials and sets session variables and redirects the user to panel.php

```
if($verified)
{
$_SESSION['unid']=$unid;
$wel="Welcome :";
$_SESSION['una']=$user;
$_SESSION['level']=$lev;
$_SESSION['pas']=$pass;
$_SESSION['wel']=$wel;
header("location:panel.php");
}
```

On the panel.php I have the code,

```
<?php
ob_start();
if(session_id()==''){
session_start();
}

if($_SESSION['una'] == "")
{
header("location:index.php");
}
```

When i login through index.php, Though the sessions data cannot be read, panel.php opens like it would normally with sessions

On refreshing the page, the sessions are gone and page redirects!

Any explanation for this behavior?

PHP V5.3.10

Comment: Where do you start the `Session` on `index.php`?

Comment: At the very first line, I have session_start();

Answer (score 0):

You always need to call `session_start()` at the start of your page. It doesn't actually start a new session, but rather initializes the session, including the loading of session variables. It's usually the first thing you do, and usually not only under conditions like in your current panel.php.

Comment: I just need a logic to why the session conditions are satisfied or seem to be satisfied on the very next page when sessions are never stored! 
I know session_start() needs to be placed at the start.. but I have deliberately set up the code the way it is.  

I'm able to login and immediately redirect the request(modifying headers) to another page (which requires login too) and it works! but after the first request, sessions come back to their normal behavior.

Comment: If session information is not stored, then all session information will be gone by the end of every request. So, when you direct to the other page, the other page will know nothing about any of the session variables of the previous one. A redirect is actually just a new request. It's merely a header in the response that tells the browser to do a new request. It's not that session information is somehow partially persistent if you are just fast enough...

Comment: EXACTLY !! That is exactly the reason why I started this thread.. 
That is exactly what i had in my head but this weird case got me thinking! 
I guess its got something to do with the server' configuration.